# How do I adjust the font size of a tetxblock control depending on the length of the text string that it contains?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I have a textblock and I pull items out of a database and I want to make the text fit on one line. How do I programmatically adjust the font size such that the entire line fits on the phone screen?

Thank you.

Comment: One workaround would be to calculate the number of characters and update the `fontsize` resource of the textblock before updating the `text` property. I'd suggest that, if you have a limit to how long your text can be, then use the biggest legible fontsize which can fit all the content in one line and use it for all text.

Comment: Check out this implementation here: http://edventuro.us/2010/03/an-auto-scaling-textblock-for-silverlight/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using what Jared Bienz linked to.